# MATLab help involving Linear Algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab

I am trying to understand what is happening here..

```
A = floor(10*rand(3));
b = sum(A')';
z = ones(3,1);
```

If I solve the system $Ax = b$, the solution is identical to the z vector..

I take `inv(A) * b` $=$ a column vector of ones, which is equivalent to what z outputs.

What is the reason for this? I am new to MATLab and Linear Algebra.

Comment: do you know how matrix multiplication works?

Comment: What is it that you do not understand?

Comment: Yes. I am just not very good with Matlab

Comment: The `sum(A')'` computes the row sums of $A$. You can achieve the same effect by computing $A z$. Do you see the connection?

Comment: it doesnt matter in this case if you are good with matlab or not. sum(A') is just summing the rows or columns of the transpose of the matrix A. So if you multiply a matrix with a vector of ones then this is the same with b=sum(A'), thats all.

Comment: ahh, ok, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was given in comments: your $b$ is the same as $Az$, so it's no surprise you get $z$ as the solution.

Practical remark: use `A\b` instead of `inv(A)*b`. The command `inv(A)*b` inverts the matrix $A$ and multiplies $b$ by it, which is **not** an efficient way to solve a linear system. The command `A\b` invokes an efficient built-in solver, which employs some adaptive algorithm to produce the solution.

Also, your code will sometimes produce an output different from $z$. Namely, when the random matrix $A$   happens to be singular:

```
Warning: Matrix is singular to working precision. 

ans =

   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
```